# Javascript : How should I run one `for`, for two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have:

```
var array1 = [];
var array2 = [];
```

`array1` contains `1`,`2`

`array2` contains `3`,`4`

And I want to do this:

```
for(var a in array1){
    for(var b in array2){
         doSomething(array1[a],array2[b]);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that function `doSomething()` runs twice for each array because of the two `for`'s.

How should run it just once but with all of the arrays?

**EDIT**

The numbers are not in ascending order! In my real project they are `ID`'s what can be any number in any order.

Comment: This depends on what you're trying to do. Your code will doSomething for every combination of array1 X array2, so you'll get four calls of doSomething. If you're trying to do the first element of both, then the second element of both, etc, follow Matti's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `for..in` for looping through arrays. Use an index variable:

```
for (var i = 0, len = array1.length; i < len; i++) {
    doSomething(array1[i], array2[i]);
}
```

This of course assumes they're the same length.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Because you were the first I will accept your answer in 4 minutes after the system let me do it!

Comment: Note that the advice “You shouldn't use `for..in` for looping through arrays” is good for *all* cases, not just when you have two arrays. `for...in` on an `Array` is almost always a mistake, it iterates the object's property names (not just integer indexes) in any arbitrary order.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* this is what you're after:

```
for(var i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
  doSomething(array1[i],array2[i]);
}
```

This loops through both arrays, using the first for the length, and taking the element at the same index in both for each `doSomething()` call.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that both arrays have the exact same length, you can do the following:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    doSomething(array1[i], array2[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to concatenate two arrays together. Use the concat() function:

```
var jointArray = array1.concat(array2);
for(var i=0; i < jointArray.length; i++) {
 doSomething(jointArray[i]);
}
```

See:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Answer (score 1):

This if array arent same length

```
for (var i = 0, i < (array1.length <= array2.length ? array1.length : array2.length); i++) {
    doSomething(array1[i], array2[i]);
}
```

Comment: I would use `Math.min` and store the minimum length on a variable to avoid that comparison on each iteration, e.g.: `for (var i = 0, len = Math.min(a1.length, a2.length); i < len; i++) { }`

Answer (score 1):

DoSomething will run 4 times. If you want it to just run through the values both list together, remove the second for loop and replace b in DoSomething with a.